# Proper way to send data back to Razor model page

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I'm trying to relay an error message back to the page when for example the username a client chooses is already in use by another user using Razor model pages.

I'm currently using ViewData[...] from cs to relay a message to the Razor cshtml page.

```cs
[BindProperty]
        public UserView UserView { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }


            if(_context.User.Where(user => user.Username == UserView.Username).FirstOrDefault() != null)
            {
                ViewData["Error"] = "That username is already in use by another user!";
                return Page();
            }
       }
```

CSHTML:

```html
@if (ViewData["Error"] != null)
{
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        swal({
            title: "Error!",
            text: '@ViewData["Error"]',
            icon: "error",
        });
    });
    </script>
}
```

This works fine, but I cannot find a lot of resources for using razor pages and most of what I find is using aspnet core MVC. Basically, I'm asking if this is fine and if there may be a better way.

Comment: Try to use ajax to call the handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of ModelState 
E.g

```
if(_context.User.Where(user => user.Username == UserView.Username).FirstOrDefault() != null)
{
      ModelState.AddModelError("DuplicateUser", "That username is already in use by another user!");

      return View();
}
```

And in view use

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("DuplicateUser")
```

Comment: Is there a more generic way to access the model error? Like say I wanted to trigger a pop up for other errors instead of a form validation error? Like @if(HasModelError()) <script> alert(@ModelError()); </script>